# You purchased stock for \$1m. What is the probability that it is worth more than $30m after 10 years?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

The change in value of the investment **each year** is modeled as follows:

Divided by 2: 1/4

Remain unchanged: 3/8

Doubles: 1/4

Quadruples: 1/8

Where I'm at: I'm aware that this needs to be formulated into a normal distribution, but I'm not sure how to come up with the right formula, or how to correctly approximate it to normal. Would really appreciate some insights!

Comment: yes! sorry for being unclear

Comment: So that you have something to compare with I did a quick numerical study with $10^6$ samples to find $p \approx 0.254$.

Comment: ...and the exact answer is $p=0.255089$ found by going through all the $4^{10}$ possibillites numerically ($4^{10} \approx 10^6$ so this is acctually not that much work...for a computer).

Comment: hi, what do you mean by $10^6$ samples? are you saying 0.255089 is the probability i'm looking for?

Comment: I generate $10^6$ samples of $10$ year periods (each sample consists or drawing random numbers to evolve the money from year to year) and in the end check how many of the samples have money-after-$10$-years $> 30\$$. Yes, $p=0.255089$ is the exact result (given that I have not made any mistakes). However this agrees very well with the probabilistic result I found before so it seems plausible. btw if you have mathematica, I can give you the code so that you can check this yourself.

Comment: thanks. i'm trying to determine the formula to use to approximate them, rather than just obtain the answer, as that would give me more insight. i know that since n = 30, the evolution of the investment can be normally approximated somehow, but i'm just unable to figure out exactly how. i was informed that i need to find a formula that resembles $2^∑Xi$ but i don't know how to manipulate the summation to give me what i want.

Answer (score 1):

No normal (even continuous) distribution would fit your evolution rules, which are clearly discrete (if only because $P(X_{t+1} = X_t) = 0 \not= 3/8$.

With your evolution probabilities, the best you can do IMO is to enumerate all possible values of the stock in year $n$ for $n \le 10$ and then compute the probabilities each year using a probability tree ([this](http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/probability-tree-diagrams.html) is Google's first result).

PS: you may want to enumerate values for $\log_2 (X_t/X_0)$ (if $X_t$ is your value in year $t$) so transitions from $t$ to $t+1$ are $-1$, $+0$, $+1$ and $+2$.

PPS: if really you wanted to fit a normal distribution, I'd suggest you compute the expectation and variance of your distribution for $X_t/X_{t-1}$ and use these as $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ parameters for your normal dist. (with common notations, found for instance [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)).

But again, that would be a very poor fit (notice that your distribution is skewed, i.e. not symmetrical).

**edit**

To get the exact result (modulo numerical/rounding errors) with Excel (or any spreadsheet editor), here is a hint https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjSBT.png (look at I22's formula). Basically, noting $Y_t = \log_2 (X_t/X_{t-1})$, you go from one column/date $t$ to the next by using the fact that $$\displaystyle P(Y_t=a) = \sum_{i \in \{-1,0,1,2\}} P(Y_{t-1}=a-i)P(a-i \rightarrow a)$$
where the transition probabilities $P(a\rightarrow b)$ do not depend on $t$ ($Y$ is a Markov chain, but you don't need to know that to understand this simple case). Then copy-paste your formula over all possible values for $t = 1 \ldots 11$ and sum all probabilities in the last column corresponding to cases where $Y_{11} \le \log_2(30)$. Takes 5 minutes all-in.

Comment: hi, yes i do believe that i'm supposed to use normal approximation for this problem. supposedly the formula should resemble $2^\sum X_i$

Comment: also, i'm quite sure doing the probability tree is not the right approach to doing this problem... i actually did do the probability tree and it was really large. i'm confident the solution is supposed to be much more compact than that.